# Centre heading in 2 by 2 table

Tags: tables, text-manipulation

In my 2 by 2 table, I would like to position the headings 'Ashley' and Matt' so they are always centred with respect to the text adjacent columns. I have included a picture of the ideal position (red boxes).

Is this possible?

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}%this changes the page geometry i.e. margins left, right, top and bottom
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{titleps,microtype,setspace,amsmath,SIunits,tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell,ltablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library}
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
        topsep     = 0pt,
        partopsep  = 0pt,
        leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
}}

\keepXColumns

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ r p{50mm} p{50mm}}
    \cline{2-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{}
    &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Heading}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Heading} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    Ashley & There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. \par There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. & There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. \\
    %cline{1-3}
    Matt & There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. \par There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. & There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. \par There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
            X
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  % content of `X` column is now centered
            X
            @{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{\textbf{Goal}}& \thead{\textbf{Task}} & \thead{\textbf{Action}} \\
        \midrule
        Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects
        &   Task 1:  Access and account set up
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item   Text.

            Text.
            \item Join the project.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate the ease in learning to map
        &   Task 2:  Learning how to map
        &   Read tutorial   \\
        \addlinespace
        Contribute data
        &   Task 3: Contributing data by classifying maps
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item Begin mapping.
            \item Text.

            Text.
            \item Review maps classified.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it
        & -- & --                   \\
        \bottomrule
        \vspace{-18mm}%needed otherwise the table gets lost between pagebreaks. 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Picture - ideal position 
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `p{...}` column type use `m{...}`:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures.
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}%this changes the page geometry i.e. margins left, right, top and bottom
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{titleps,microtype}
\usepackage{setspace, amsmath, siunitx}% SIunits is consider obsolete
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex, makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{library}
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
        topsep     = 0pt,
        partopsep  = 0pt,
        leftmargin = *,
%        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
}}

\keepXColumns

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{r m{50mm} m{50mm}}
    \cline{2-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{}
    &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Heading}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Heading} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    Ashley
        & There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. \par
        There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. & There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use.    \\
    %cline{1-3}
    Matt
        & There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. \par
        There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. & There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. \par
          There is virtually no feedback given by the interface during use. \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
    \label{table:comparison of techniques}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
            X
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  % content of `X` column is now centered
            X
            @{}}
        \toprule
    \thead{Goal} & \thead{Task} & \thead{Action}    \\
        \midrule
    Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects
        &   Task 1:  Access and account set up
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item   Text.

            Text.
            \item Join the project.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate the ease in learning to map
        &   Task 2:  Learning how to map
        &   Read tutorial   \\
        \addlinespace
        Contribute data
        &   Task 3: Contributing data by classifying maps
        &   \begin{enumerate}
            \item Begin mapping.
            \item Text.

            Text.
            \item Review maps classified.
        \end{enumerate}     \\
        \addlinespace
        Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it
        & -- & --                   \\
        \bottomrule
        \vspace{-18mm}%needed otherwise the table gets lost between pagebreaks.
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]